# SelectMany for multiple arrays

Tags: c#, linq

I need to make all possible distinct strings, which are inserted array elements.

```
string[] arr1 = { "b", "c", "a"};
string[] arr2 = { "u", "o", "c"};
...
string[] arrN = { "f", "h", "k"};
```

After that, it turns out an array of strings (**it is important to keep order of arrays**):

> bu...f; co...h; cu...k; ...

For a known amount of arrays I do so:

```
String[] str = arr1.SelectMany(
            i => arr2.SelectMany(
                k => arr3.Select(
                    l => string.Concat(i, k, l)))).ToArray();
```

How to do the same thing for an array of arrays?

Comment: It's not at all clear to me where the "distinct" part comes in... but basically you want to convert an array of arrays of strings to an array of strings, by sort of "pivoting"? Is each array the same size?

Comment: Show what you mean by array of arrays

Comment: See my answer to the duplicate question.